# How do I put a javascript variable inside a php query?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, integration

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

   var list = document.getElementsByClassName('sortByTestName');

   for (var i = 0;i<list.length; i++) 
   {
    list[i].addEventListener('click', function() 
    {
         //window.alert(this.innerHTML);
         var current = this.innerHTML;
         var phpContent = 
                                        "<?php 

                   $queryFlightBit = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT hss_test.workOrderMasterKey FROM demo.hss_test where hss_test.testName ='current'");

         ?>";
        
    }); 
    
   }

  </script>
```

If you take a look at the nested php code in queryFlightBit, I need to run the queryn with the javascript variable current. How do I go about doing this? Is there a way I can run a php query with a javascript variable?

Comment: You want to do a serverside function with a clientside variable without a HTTP-Request?

Comment: May be some help to understand: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: PHP is executed on the server. JS is executed on the Client, long after all the PHP code is already done. The way to do this is to do another HTTP  request including that data with JavaScript, preferably with AJAX.